# How to get the current input value (radio button, text input)?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to program a live search in JavaScript and PHP but I'm having lots of problems. On my site are two radio buttons to define the category and a text input below.

I've already tested the keyup function in JavaScript but it didn't worked out for me. Is there a alternative?

```
<div class="container" style="text-align:center;">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="">
            <form>
              <input type="radio" name="penis" id="cat_user" value="user" checked> User
              <input type="radio" name="penis" id="cat_cat" style="padding-right: 5px;" value="catmatice"> Category<br><br>
              <input type="text" class="input_text" name="search" id="search" autocomplete="off" placeholder="search user name here....">
            </form>
          </div>
         <div class="grind search">
           <ul>
             <div id="output"></div>
           </ul>
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if (document.getElementById('cat_user').checked) {
    alert('HALLO');
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
      var query = $(this).val();
      if (query != "") {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'search.php',
          method: 'POST',
          data: {opt:'user',query:query},
          success: function(data){

            $('#output').html(data);
            $('#output').css('display', 'block');

            $("#search").focusin(function(){
              $('#output').css('display', 'block');
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        $('#output').css('display', 'none');
      }
    });

  }

  if (document.getElementById('cat_cat').checked) {
    alert('LUL');
    $("#search").keyup(function(){
      var query = $(this).val();
      if (query != "") {
        $.ajax({
          url: 'search.php',
          method: 'POST',
          data: {opt:'cat',query:query},
          success: function(data){

            $('#output').html(data);
            $('#output').css('display', 'block');

            $("#search").focusin(function(){
              $('#output').css('display', 'block');
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        $('#output').css('display', 'none');
      }

    });

  }
});
```

Comment: There are other keyboard events you could use, such as `keydown` or `input`. What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: `it didn't worked out for me` - why not? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch the event listeners order.

They must go before you do the "cat_user" is checked validation, otherwise you will only be listening for keyup events if the "cat_user" is already checked on page loaded.

There's also no need to repeat the whole code.

```js
$(function(){
  $("#search").input(function(){
    var searchValue = $(this).val();
    if (searchValue == "") {
       $('#output').css('display', 'none');
    }else if (document.getElementById('cat_user').checked) {
      fetchSearch(searchValue, 'user');
    }else if(document.getElementById('cat_cat'),checked){
      fetchSearch(searchValue, 'cat');
    }else{
      $('#output').css('display', 'none');
    }
  })

  function fetchSearch(searchValue, searchType){
     $.ajax({
          url: 'search.php',
          method: 'POST',
          data: {opt: searchType, query: searchValue},
          success: function(data){
            $('#output').html(data);
            $('#output').css('display', 'block');
          }
        });
  }

})


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out if a checkbox is checked or not using this jQuery function:

```
document.getElementById('cat_cat').is(":checked")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this way

```
$('input[type="text"][id="search"]').on('change', function(e) {
  const selectedVal = $('input[type="radio"][name="penis"]:checked').val();
  $.ajax({
          url: 'search.php',
          method: 'POST',
          data: {opt:selectedVal,query:e['target']['value']},
          success: function(data){

            $('#output').html(data);
            $('#output').css('display', 'block');

            $("#search").focusin(function(){
              $('#output').css('display', 'block');
            });
          }
        });
      } else {
        $('#output').css('display', 'none');
      }
    });
});
```

Also you can replace change event with needed event.